# Не работает вставка url админ панели через атрибут name

Tags: python, django, django-urls

При попытке обратиться к url админ панели по атрибуту name, указанному в urls.py, страница выдаёт ошибку, что не существует такого паттерна:
[image: Скриншот ошибки]

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '',
        ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by("-pub_datetime")[:20],
                         template_name="Main/index.html"),
        name='index'
    ),
    path(
        'admin/',
        admin.site.urls,
        name='admin'
    ),
    path(
        'contacts/',
        views.contacts,
        name='contacts'
    )
]
```

header.html:

```html
<header>
    <ul id="header_menu">
        <li><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href = "{% url 'index' %}">Главная Страница</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-lg btn-info" href = "{% url 'contacts' %}">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" href = "{% url 'admin' %}">Панель администратора</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
</header>
```

Ни с чем другим таких проблем не возникает. Ошибка не критичная, можно и вручную 'admin/' прописать, но хотелось бы иметь возможность пользоваться этим функционалом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `{% url 'admin:index' %}` и уберите `name` из `admin url`.

Comment: Да, сработало. Благодарю.